# Advanced search with google API

Tags: java

I've read here: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/?hl=iw-IL#CustomBranding
about how to use Google Search in Java.

Still, I couldn't find any site on the web that talks about advanced search.

I want to get only the results from the last 24 hours.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `&as_qdr=d` at the end of your URL.
Example:
 Search for "test": http://www.google.com/search?q=test
 Search for "test" with "Past 24 hours" option: http://www.google.com/search?q=test&as_qdr=d

Comment: where I can find all the of those "GET" options ?

Comment: How can I do only for "the past hour" results ?

Comment: Simple, Just search something with Google advanced search, then you can find all these options in your browser address bar.

Comment: There is no "the past hour" option in the Google advanced search.